# Is it possible to do OAuth on WP8 without embeded browser?

Tags: windows-phone-8, oauth

This is for doing OAuth with the Pocket API, it specifically states that using an embedded webview is a violation of the terms of use, all OAuth examples I can find on WP8 seem to rely on the embedded webbrowser to do the authentication.

Is it not possible to use the default browser in WP8 to do the authentication and then redirect back into the App? I have done this in Android before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you read their documentation, it says that you need to provide a redirect URL. I am not sure if it will work, but you could try adding URI association to your application and specify callback URL that will return back to your app.

Then, when your application is reactivated from the default browser, you should know that the user has authorized it.

Thus you could use `WebBrowserTask` for that, but I am unaware if you can call local app-URI from browser.